# Javascript class static method vs function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

The following 2 blocks of code:

```
const Game = {
    start: () => { ...run some logic; return true; },
    stop: () => { ...run some logic; return false; }
}
```

```
class Game {
    static start() { ...run some logic; return true; }
    static stop() { ...run some logic; return false; }
}
```

Both works when running `Game.start()` or `Game.stop()`.

Are there any pros/cons for either one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever want one instance of this object, then there really is no meaningful difference.

Both the `Game` object declaration and the `Game` class declaration are both just singletons (one pre-declared instance of an object with some properties).

Where it would really make more sense to use a `class` is if you want to construct more than one of these objects and you want each instance to have its own separate instance data or you want to inherit from another definition.  That's really where the differences and features in a `class` are apparent and useful.  All of that can also be simulated without a `class` (as we did before the `class` keyword was added to the language), but using a class makes inheritance and defining objects that will be dynamically constructed much simpler and more declarative.

So, as it is shown in your question with just a pre-defined singleton, no meaningful advantage to prefer one over the other.